# Chosing first two from the array and the add +(plus) for rest of them

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, redux, antd

I am developing an react frontend, where I am actually listing using table view, Now its getting array, Its rendering perfect. Now I want to add one more column, but there I want to show data from array of a particular array within array object.
Meaning: I have data like Array then objects, where I am reading data. Then within that data I have another array object where I have to read data.(Something like below)

```
 [
        {_id: "535345345345345345345", name: "Activity", description: "this is activity", filters: [
                {_id: "49823476237423984", name: "ACTIVITY filter", origin: "ACTIVITY"
                },
                {_id: "49823476237423985", name: "USER filter", origin: "USER"
                },
                {_id: "49823476237423985", name: "STUDENT filter", origin: "STUDENT"
                }
            ]
        },
{_id: "535345345345345345346", name: "Student", description: "this is Student", filters: [
                {_id: "49823476237423994", name: "ACTIVITY filter", origin: "ACTIVITY"
                },
                {_id: "49823476237423895", name: "USER filter", origin: "USER"
                },
                {_id: "49823476237423989", name: "STUDENT filter", origin: "STUDENT"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
```

Now this is my code of react

```
const columns = [ {
            key: 'name',
            title: 'Name',
            dataIndex: 'name',
          }, {
            key: 'description',
            title: 'Description',
            dataIndex: 'description',
          },
        {
          key: 'filters',
          title: 'Filters',
          dataIndex: '', // to add logic here
        }];
    
const tableProps = {
            className: 'table',
            columns,
            dataSource: data,
            pagination: false,
            size: 'small',
          };

          const tableNode = (
            <Fragment>
              <Table {...tableProps} />
              {data.length ? null : <EmptyTablePlaceholder />} // here in data I have all the data of which I am showing to table
            </Fragment>
          );
```

With above code I am getting below result
[image]

And I am expecting something like below
[image]
Update: This is below code trying to do the same

```
  {
              key: 'filters',
              width: '10%',
              title: 'Filters',
              dataIndex: 'filters',
              render: (filters) =>{
                const updatedItem = {filters: filters.length > 2 ? `${filters[0].origin}, ${filters[1].origin} + ${filters.length -2}` : filters.length > 1 ? `${filters[0].origin}, ${filters[1].origin}` : `${filters[0].origin}`}

                return (
                  <div>
                    {updatedItem}
                  </div>
                )
              }
```

How can I make this possible? Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `record` from antd table column `render`, check the depending table [docs](https://ant.design/components/table/#Column) too.

By overriding the `render` method and calling `record.filters` as a map you can gain access to your `filter.origin` property. E.g.:

```
 ...
{
key: "filters",
title: "Filters",
width: 200,
render: (text, record) => (
  <span>
    {record.filters.map((filter, index) => (
      <>
        {index < 2 && (
          <span style={{ textTransform: "capitalize" }}>
            {filter.origin.toLowerCase()}
            {index === 0 && record.filters.length > 1 && <span>, </span>}
          </span>
        )}
      </>
    ))}
    {record.filters.length > 2 && (
      <span> +{record.filters.length - 2} </span>
    )}
  </span>
)
}
...
```

Here is a working [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/pedantic-darkness-81wd8?file=/index.js:317-675).

---

**Edit1**: Updated code to add `+1` for `filter.length > 2`

**Edit2**: Updated code and sandbox to add `+N` for `filter.length > 2` + Minor changes

Comment: Hey. I want to show only 2, rest of them can add as `+1` or `+2` or `+3` and so on... as many it has, it should show `+N`number but it should show only two at first...then rest of them in `+N` numbers..

Comment: Hm yeah,  that is hardcoded. Maybe you want to think about your homework too? ;-) or Just add `{record.filters.length - 2} ` instead of the hardcoded number 1. I will update the example later.

Comment: Unable to do it, Can you please help?

Comment: Done. If your request was satisfied please accept and [vote](https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote).

Answer (score 0):

You can update the data source and update the filters attribute of the data array using the following function,

```
const updatedDataSource = data.map((item) => {
    if(item.filters) {
        const updatedItem = {...item, filters: item.filters.length > 2 ? `${item.filters[0].origin}, ${item.filters[1].origin} + ${item.filters.length -2}` : item.filters.length > 1 ? `${item.filters[0].origin}, ${item.filters[1].origin}` : `${item.filters[0].origin}`}
        return updatedItem;
    }
    return item;
})
```

And then you can pass the updatedDataSource in your table props. One thing to remmeber is capitalizing the filter origin. Currently it will print `STUDENT, ACTIVITY + 1`.

Comment: Data is dynamic, if data is 10 or more than that your code is not meeting the expecting result/

Comment: Can you check the updated code, I am trying to render your code in column element. Its not working, can you help there